# What does the dedication "To The Other Three" mean?

Tags: meaning, john-lockwood-kipling

The book [*Beast and Man in India*](http://www.kiplingsociety.co.uk/rg_beastandman.htm) by John Lockwood Kipling (father of the more famous Rudyard Kipling), which is freely available on [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/40708/40708-h/40708-h.htm), has the following cryptic dedication:

> TO THE OTHER THREE
>
> [image: strange picture]

What does this mean? Who are "the other three"? The other three *what*?

Comment: Inspired by [this closed question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/447469/87724) on English SE, which is unfortunately too old to migrate here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**It appears to be a dedication to the author's family.**

I haven't got any solid proof for this, but it's the solution I've seen put forward in a number of places, probably all ultimately deriving from J. H. McGivering, "Kipling and Son: a Successful Partnership", *The Kipling Journal*, December 1970, pp. 7-14. This article can be read either [as a scanned PDF](http://www.kiplingjournal.com/acrobat/KJ176.pdf) or [in plain text](http://www.kiplingjournal.com/textfiles/KJ176.txt) at the Kipling Journal website. It's about the strong bonds within the Kipling family, especially between John Lockwood and his son Rudyard. From the very end of the article:

> So much, then, for a quick look at two essentially lovable characters : the father dedicates his book
>
> TO THE OTHER THREE
>
> and the son never fails to show his family that gratitude and affection they so richly deserve; in fact that remark addressed to the Curator by the lama might well have been used by either Kipling to the other
> "We be craftsmen together, thou and I".

This piece was also delivered as a talk at the Discussion Meeting of the Kipling Society on 15 July 1970, where apparently it inspired many questions some of which remained unanswered.

In [a response to a question emailed to a Rudyard Kipling mailing list earlier this year](https://www.jiscmail.ac.uk/cgi-bin/webadmin?A2=rudyard-kipling;1ec8d809.1805), John Radcliffe said:

> Surely the ‘other three’ members of the Kiplings’ family square, which consisted of Alice, Rudyard, Trix, and Lockwood.

This conclusion was further supported by Mary Hamer, who said:

> Agreed. Bearing in mind also that Christmas number they put together, published as ‘Quartette’.

(Both Mary Hamer and John Radcliffe are officers in [the Kipling Society](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Kipling_Society).) Brian Harris, the querent in this email thread, also posted his findings on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-does-the-dedication-To-The-Other-Three-in-the-book-Beast-and-Man-in-India-John-Lockwood-Kipling-1891-mean).

The phrase "family square" was indeed used a lot for the four members of the Kipling family - you can find a lot of results online by searching the web for `kipling "family square"` - so it seems reasonable that John Lockwood's dedication was, as many are, to his family.